# Dell Ultrasharp monitor: Connect Both VGA and DVID

Tags: display, input

I have a Dell Ultrasharp 20" monitor which is capable of dual display. Here is the device:
http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=320-4687

I want to hook up two different computers to it; both of them have DVI-D and VGA outputs. However, due to non-available of some cables/adapters I'd like to hook up one computer using a DVI cable--it is hooked up and working fine and use a VGA cable to output from the other computer to the VGA port of the monitor.

Is it possible to do, without harming any system? There is a switch in front of the monitor to show appropriate display.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works fine . . . I run several of the exact same monitor (UltraSharp 2007FP) with both VGA and DVI inputs, toggling as needed.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to get a VGA cable and see what happens..

Comment: Works fine! But connecting the VGA cable to the VGA port on my Dell Optiplex 745 caused an error in boot time--something like that not compatible VGA and needed to connect some adapter. So I plugged the VGA cable to a DVI connector (via an adapter) and the error went away. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with any monitor, it is not a problem. Its just like switching hdmi ports on the tv when you go to source and switch to satellite hdm1 etc etc.